# Any way to make vim work as vscode (at least close )?

Tags: vim

I have to say the most tough wall between me and vim is it lack easy way to do

1. match whole word
2. case sensitive
3. multiple cursor

[image]

match whold word means

[image]

About multiple cursor, there is an answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784408/vim-multiline-editing-like-in-sublimetext

It is too complocated. `ctrl+d` select word block, one click, match one more selection would be prefered.

What I want is just as simple as posible, no metter install some plugin .
I usually use vim to check some file , but when I need to find and replace  or use multiple cursor I have to switch to vscode or sublime .

This is a big wall for me to use vim . 
How can I config/plugined vim make it easy enough for the three point.

Comment: For next time... Please post one question at a time. Here you posted three separate questions (matching whole words, case sensitivity [with not much detail], and multiple cursors), so it's hard to address it all. Posting them separately would help you get better answers on each of them.

Comment: You might want to check out the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim!

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to address your questions here, let's see if I can help you with some of them.

#### Match whole word

You can match a whole word while searching in Vim by using the [`\<`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%3C) and [`\>`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%3E) anchors around the word.

For example:

```
/\<withColumn\>
```

But an **easier way** around that is to **use the [`*`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#star) and [`#`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%23) commands**, which will search for the word under the cursor (`*` forward, `#` backwards) and will automatically use the `\<` and `\>` anchors when doing so. I find these tend to be the most useful when I'm writing code, since I usually have occurrences of the function/variable/class name I'm looking for close by, so I can just navigate there and use `*` to find the next occurrence, and then repeat with `n` to keep finding further occurrences.

If you tend to use the `/` search more often and you'd like to save on typing `\<` and `\>`, consider adding a mapping, such as:

```
nnoremap g/ /\<\><left><left>
```

The `g/` key sequence will start a search, then type the `\<` and `\>` for you and finally go left twice so the cursor is right at the middle of them, ready for you to type the search term, which will then be searched as a whole word only.

#### Case sensitivity

You didn't really go into details there... But by default searches in Vim are case sensitive. But it's possible you're using a `.vimrc` that is configuring them as case insensitive, or case insensitive in some situations, so it's good to understand the settings that control that.

- [`set ignorecase`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27ignorecase%27): This will make searches case insensitive, so make sure you don't have that set if what you want is case sensitive search. You can check the current status of this setting with `:set ignorecase?` and you can disable it with `:set noignorecase` (or `:set noic`.)
- [`set smartcase`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27smartcase%27): This one makes searches case insensitive *only when* there are only lowercase letters in the search term *and* `'ignorecase'` is also set. So, more precisely, this makes them case sensitive when there are uppercase characters in the search term, even if `'ignorecase'` is set.

It's possible you have both of these set (it's quite a popular setting) and you're seeing case insensitive searches when your search terms are all lowercase... So you might want to look into removing `'ignorecase'` from your `.vimrc` or overriding it explicitly with `set noignorecase` if always case sensitive is what you want.

You can also override these in particular searches, with [`\C` and `\c`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2Fignorecase) as part of your search term.

If you want your mapping for searching for entire word to always be case sensitive, consider this mapping:

```
nnoremap g/ /\C\<\><left><left>
```

That does not depend on the setting of `'ignorecase'` at all.

#### Multiple cursors

You linked to another question, but I'm not sure if you saw the answer mentioning a plug-in that does exactly what you want. The top voted answer there only talks about visual block mode, which is very useful but doesn't work when you're dealing with identifiers that are not aligned and not on consecutive lines.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24203519/9447571), on the other hand, mentioned the [vim-multiple-cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors) plugin, which, as far as I can tell, does the exact same as multiple cursors in VSCode or Sublime.

(I'm not really a user of this plug-in, or a user of VSCode, or a user of Sublime, so I couldn't tell for sure, but looking at the video, it looks like what you describe.)

I'd encourage you to take a closer look at this plug-in and see if it fits your use case.

However, I'd like to point out that, even *without* multiple cursors, you *can* perform large scale changes to files in Vim by just using the basic commands, without the real need for any plug-ins at all.

I recommend the article ["You don’t need more than one cursor in vim" by Christoph Hermann](https://medium.com/@schtoeffel/you-don-t-need-more-than-one-cursor-in-vim-2c44117d51db) for a great take on this topic, with many particular examples and advanced use cases far beyond what you'd be able to accomplish with multiple cursors.

So, in short, if you want multiple cursors, check out the [vim-multiple-cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors) plugin, but if you want to learn commands in Vim that can take on the same kind of editing tasks, read the article (or look for it online, you'll surely find more posts about efficiently refactoring code with Vim.)